# How do I use Jquery UI .css files only for some components?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I downloaded Jquery UI (http://jqueryui.com/download/) I marked everything except accordion since I have my own css for that. My main page has a menu in an Accordion, in this main page I don't use JQuery UI .css file. When I click any item in the menu it loads a page that uses JQuery UI .css file and it completly changes my accordion.

I want to be able to use JQuery UI .css file for Dialog, Datepicker,... but I don't want it in my accordion. Is there a way to do that or do I have to create my own css for all the other components?

Comment: did you find any solution to tho issue so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to make abuse of `!important` attribute or exploit css class specification feature. Simply add more classes to your accordion and be consequently more specific in your css selectors. Including your css after the jQueryUI standard css can help as well.